# Kubernetes ingress / NGINX re-write does not match while regex seems valid

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to filter out all paths that begin with `/something`. While the regex seems PCRE valid by online testers, the result is `404` for all paths:

```json
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 80          
        path: /^([^something].*)
```

Tried to play with the regex (e.g, `path: /(^[^something])(.*)`), but still get `404` for all.

What am I missing?

Using `v1.12.2` client with `v1.14.1` server.

Comment: can you try adding this annotation -  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"

Comment: if I do that, it makes some weird certificate issues ("Your connection is not private")

Comment: I am not sure if I understood what you want to achieve. Could you elaborate? 
Did you see https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/rewrite#rewrite-target

Comment: I would like to deny all incoming requests that begin with `/something`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deny all traffic to `/something` you should use `Nginx` annotations called [server-snipped](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet). It will allow you to add custom configuration.

It would look like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
   name: nginx-snippet
   annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |

      location /something {

           deny all;  
      }
```

Fimilar example can be found on [Github](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/161#issuecomment-322224255) thread.

You can also consider second option with 2 `ingress` objects and `authentication`. This was mentioned in another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51894604/11148139).

In addition, you can deny access not only by location but also with specific IP. It can be obtain using annotation called [whitelist-source-range](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range).

Comment: Is there a way to separate paths so that it goes two two different backends? I have two react apps which i'd like to access them differently,