# Nginx-ingress Kubernetes routing with basic auth

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I cannot set basic auth up on one of my paths. I would like to have `/auth` path secured by basic auth, all the others paths don't need basic auth. So I created two ingress files which point to the same backend:

Non-auth ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /.*
            backend:
              serviceName: example-service
              servicePort: 4000
```

Auth-ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: auth-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "false"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /auth
            backend:
              serviceName: example-service
              servicePort: 4000
```

All secrets are set correctly.
What am I missing and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create another service for backend which need authentication:

1. `main-ingress` contains the spec for the service(s) which don't require authentication through nginx eg. `example-service`.
2. `auth-ingress` contains the spec for the service(s) which require authentication (basic in my case) through nginx eg. auth-service.

Your `auth-ingress` should looks like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: auth-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "false"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /auth
            backend:
              serviceName: auth-service
              servicePort: <auth-service-port>
```

Also you can try in first ingress try to deny traffic to `/auth` path in `main-ingress`.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    
      location /auth {

           deny all;  
      }
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: example-tls
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /.*
            backend:
              serviceName: example-service
              servicePort: 4000
```

Take a look: [ingress-nginx-issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1893), [kubernetes-ingress-network-deny-some-paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874503/kubernetes-ingress-network-deny-some-paths/51894604#51894604), [kubernetes-ingress-nginx-re-write-does-not-match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59175976/kubernetes-ingress-nginx-re-write-does-not-match-while-regex-seems-valid).