# Nginx Ingress controller- Path based routing

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

i am running an Nginx ingress controller and wanted to allow only few path for users to connect and rest all I wanted to  block or provide an 403 error. how can i do that?

I only wanted users to allow to connect `/example` and  rest all should be  blocked.

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ingress.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /example
        backend:
          serviceName: ingress-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Can i add a nginx server-snippet?

````
     location path {
       "if the path is not matching then deny"
       deny all;
     }```
````

Comment: The nginx ingress controller comes with a default backend which responds to every request that doesn' t match your routes. You can customize that to show whatever you want or you can make your own service and use it as a default backend.

Comment: i am not interested to touch my default backend. This is only for a  one specific ```/path``` . Can i add a nginx server-snippet?   ```nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location path {
        if the path is not matching then deny. something like that
        deny all;
      }```

Comment: Your seem to be contradicting in your statements , are you looking to block everything that doesnt match /example or are you looking to block  one specific path.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. yes, am looking to block everything that doesn't match ```/example```. I only want to allow ```/example```.

Comment: Considering you don't want to touch your default backend , you can  make  a custom service that gives 403 when route matches /* and since ingress works on specificity it will  work for all routes except /example

Comment: do you have some examples or some documentation i can try?

Comment: lets chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218209/kubernetes

Comment: ok.let me join.

Comment: I am not able to enter my messages in chat room. sorry

Comment: do you know why am not able to enter the messages?

Comment: I think what you need is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874503/kubernetes-ingress-network-deny-some-paths), in another stackoverflow question. Take a look and let me know if that answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom backend using below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: custom-http-backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: custom-http-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: custom-http-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: custom-http-backend
        image: inanimate/echo-server
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: custom-http-backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: custom-http-backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

Then in your ingress add this rule

```
- host: ingress.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: custom-http-backend
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: this will give you some custom output , you can change it to what you what to show as 403.

Comment: thanks. i only wanted to send to ```custom-http-backend``` if the path is not ```/example```. so what is ``` path: /* ``` mean?

Comment: It means all path after / , and since you will have a route for /example it will include everything that except example covered with that path.

Comment: It means all path after / , and since you will have a route for /example it will include everything that except example covered with that path.

Comment: just to clarify, can't we achieve same  using ```nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet```. if the ```location``` is not matching then ```deny all```.?

Comment: i got a similar post ```https://habr.com/ru/company/flant/blog/445596/```

Comment: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-errors/

Comment: the above link talks about the same approach you mentioned. my point is can we achieve this using ```nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet``` and ```deny''' or the only way you told is the option?. I am trying to understand more.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what @Tarun Khosla mentioned which is correct, there is another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874503/kubernetes-ingress-network-deny-some-paths) with examples which might be helpful. I am posting this as a community wiki answer for better visibility for the community, feel free to expand on it.

There are 2 examples provided by @Nick Rak

---

I’ve faced the same issue and found the solution on [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1893).
To achieve your goal, you need to create two Ingresses first by default without any restriction:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
 name: ingress-test
 spec:
   rules:
   - host: host.host.com
   http:
      paths:
        - path: /service-mapping
      backend:
         serviceName: /service-mapping
         servicePort: 9042
```

Then, create a `secret` for auth as described in the [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/auth):

Creating the `htpasswd`

```
$ htpasswd -c auth foo
New password: <bar>
New password:
Re-type new password:
Adding password for user foo
```

Creating the `secret`:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic basic-auth --from-file=auth
secret "basic-auth" created
```

Second Ingress with auth for paths which you need to restrict:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-with-auth
  annotations:
    # type of authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    # name of the secret that contains the user/password definitions
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    # message to display with an appropiate context why the authentication is required
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required - foo"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: host.host.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /admin
        backend:
          serviceName: service_name
          servicePort: 80
```

According to [sedooe answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3099704/sedooe), his solution may have some issues.

---

and @sedooe

> You can use [server-snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet) annotation. [This](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/161#issuecomment-322224255) seems like exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks for the update @Nick Rak solution worked for me